# Enable Serilog's Selflog from config file

Tags: .net, serilog

The docs only show how to enable Selflog programmatically. I would like to enable/disable it by just updating the config file.

Is there a way to enable selflog from config file the same we do to define loggers and sinks?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way provided by Serilog but this how I have solved it.

1. Create a configuration in appsettings.json.

   ```
   {
     "EnableSerilogSelfLogs": "false",
   }
   ```
2. Read configuration in program.cs and call the required method.

   ```
   if(enableSelfLogs)
   {
      var fileName = File.AppendText(Path.Combine(logDir, "_SerilogSelfLogs.txt"));
      Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(TextWriter.Synchronized(fileName));
   }
   ```

hope it helps.